# Couldnt install Socket.io by npm

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm

While installing socket.io i have a problem which states Couldn't load Visual C++ component vcbuilt.exe. I tried different solution in stackflow.com like I tried installing sdk but still didn't work. Any solution ??

Comment: https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/wiki/Visual-Studio-2010-Setup

Comment: @Sirko After hours of downloading and installing it worked like a charm still i get an error stating "cannot open input file 'kernel32.lib'. Any idea on this my friend ??

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue. I managed to get it working with the linked tutorial. Btw installing that stuff under Linux is much easier. Maybe you can switch the environment.

Comment: yes. windows sucks!!!